# Race to 4 with dependency

Tags: statistics

I am trying to calculate the probability that team A wins a match series in best of seven with the probability = 0.6 to win a match.

This is easy if I consider matches to be independent to each other, but what if winner in the first match will have a slightly bigger chance in the next match?

Is there any distribution I could use for this?

Comment: Backwards Induction works for the independent case, and might work for the other but you need to be clearer about the dependence.  You can just include a state variable to tell you who won the last game if that's all that matters.  If the path dependence is more complex this will get harder.

Comment: Let's say your chance of winning the next match will increase with 10% if you wan the previous game.

Would that be enough to know to be able and calculate before any match have been played?

Comment: Well, any deterministic rules would be enough to compute things.  If worst comes to worst you can just enumerate all the paths (last resort).  You life gets a lot better if you can make the probabilities depend only on the last game though.  True path dependency is really going to be computationally painful.

Comment: Just to be clear:  with only $7$ games then there are fewer than $2^7=128$ paths.  Fewer because you stop if one team gets to $4$.  So it's not that bad a computation here, even with full path dependence.  But if you had $N$ games it gets bad fast and you would need to sample.

Comment: Yes, and thats my problem. Number of matches could increase so I was looking for an easier solution.

Comment: I figured.  Like I say, if you have no control over the dependence then you are stuck with the paths.  But if you can sum up the dependence in a convenient state variable or two then backwards induction is extremely efficient.

Comment: Here is an urn scheme that may match your intentions and also should be solvable: An urn starts with 10 balls of which 6 are green and 4 are red. For each game Team A selects a ball at random from the urn, winning if the ball is green. The green ball is replaced and another green ball is added. So the chance of winning the 2nd game given a win on the first is $7/11 > 6/10.$ (Variations are possible: Upon a loss, you could also say to add an additional red ball, if you like.)

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I will definitely look up backwards induction but could you show with an example?

lets say team A have p = 0.6 to win first match, and there chance of winning will increase with 10% after each win. What will their probability be to win the entire serie?

Comment: Like I say, that's a bad one because it depends on the entire path.  an easier one is to say $A$ wins with the first game with probability $.6$, and thereafter if $A$ won the last game, $A$ wins the next with probability $.7$ and if $A$ lost the last game, $A$ wins the next with probability $.5$.  Something like that.

Comment: Even the one I described is a little messy.  There are a lot of states to consider!  You have to create states of the form $S(a,b,\pm)$ to indicate that $A$ has won $a$ games, $b$ has won $b$ games, and where the $\pm$ tells us if $A$ won or lost the last game.

Comment: Thanks, and I cant simply solve the probability for A to win whole serie with just adding extra parameter for A to win a  match.